# How to implement an interface on a map[int] of type

Tags: dictionary, go, interface

I'm trying to build a function, that can be implemented on a map[int]T.
Im pretty new to go and wondered, if this can be done by implementing an interface.

```golang
    invoices   map[int]domain.Invoice
    bookings   map[int]domain.Booking
    projects   map[int]domain.Project
```

All of those have following in common:

```golang
type Invoice struct {
    ID         int
}
type Booking struct {
    ID         int
}
type Project struct {
    ID         int
}
```

How must I proceed to be able to implement a function that returns the next ID of all Invoices, Bookings or Projects by increasing the ID of the last Item in the respecting map of the Type?

For example:

```golang
func (i *map[int]T) nextID() int {
    return T.ID + 1
```

Comment: There's a couple of problems with this idea: first, interfaces specify only *methods*, not *fields*; second, even if you had a usable interface type, you would have to use a `map[int]MyInterface` specifically; and third, you can only declare methods on types you define, you can't declare a method on a `map` type directly.

Comment: Thank you @Adrian. Is there a clever way, with which I can indirectly declare a method on a map? Im thinking of this a List-Type like in C#, where you can Add and Count Items. `type InvoiceList struct { invoices map[int]domain.Invoice } func (il *InvoiceList) getNextID() int { ... }`  Would this by a way to go (no pun intended)?

Comment: You can declare a type `type MyMapType map[int]domain.Invoice` and then declare methods on `MyMapType`.

Answer (score 0):

`wondered, if this can be done by implementing an interface` of course you can.

I dont pretend to provide the right idiomatic way. But from what you say, all those types can be summarized into an `IDer` interface.

For that pruposes they would have to implement an interface defined as `type IDer interface { ID() int }`. This `ID()` method would have to be implemented for each struct types.
Using that common compatible implementation you can define a `map[int]IDer` and put into it `Invoice`, `Booking`, `Project` etc as long as it is compatible.

In order to prevent code duplication you could define a `type IDed struct { ID int}; func (i ID) int {return i.ID}`, and embed that within your types such as `type Invoice struct { IDed }` and so on. Doing so you can still call `var x Invoice;  x.ID=1; someid := x.ID;`

Finally, you might define you map as a type `type mapOfID map[int]IDer` and attach methods to it `func (m mapOfID) DoSomethigWithIDers(){...}`

Answer (score 0):

@mh-cbon outlined a couples of approaches.  Maps by themselves do a poor job of keeping track of the "last" item since it's not part of their storage or semantics.  One way around this would be to either keep track of the last index or the last `domain` object added to a map in order to calculate the next id:

```
type IDer interface {
    ID() int
}
type IDS struct {
    m    map[int]IDer
    last IDer
}

func (i *IDS) Add(index int, ider IDer) {
    i.m[index] = ider
    i.last = ider
}

func (i *IDS) nextID() int {
    if i.last == nil {
      return 1
    }
    return i.last.ID() + 1
}
```

The example above combines @mh-cbon's IDer interface with the ability to keep traack of the last Ider added.

[This can then be used](https://play.golang.org/p/3HUh2UKJfBj) with any of your `domain` objects as long as they implement the `IDer` interface:

```
type Invoice struct{}

func (i Invoice) ID() int { return 1 }

func main() {
    ids := &IDS{
       m: make(map[int]IDer),
    }
    ids.Add(1, Invoice{})
    fmt.Printf("Next ID: %d\n", ids.nextID())

}
```

```
Next ID: 2

Program exited.
```

Comment: And how do i handle further properties if present? Those types just have ID in common, but have more properties, than just ID, i.e. domain.Booking has Day int and Hours int. Can i still access those?

Comment: does the id generator function *need* to access them? Independent of this, yes you can type assert an interface to a concrete type to access https://tour.golang.org/methods/15 . If those items are necessary to calculate a domain objects `ID()` then they can be encapsulated in its `ID()` function you won't need to type assert.

Comment: Wow. Those are depths I did not yet discover.. https://play.golang.org/p/JfCOi1T18Mu <- Is this how you meant me to do it?

Comment: I now have a new problem with your line `func (i Invoice) ID() int { return 1 }`. This always returns 1, and nextID is always 2, even when adding more Invoices.

Comment: I fixed the problem myself and will post an answer with my solution.

Comment: Would a slice (list) type make more sense? this would allow you to get the last index since you can get the current length - 1

Comment: I thought about that also, but i want to use the advantages of map to "query" the map via an id. So `invoices[2]` returns the invoice with id 2.

Answer (score 0):

With all the information gathered I came to following answer:

https://play.golang.org/p/3RAvclRacbh

(I used "List" for easier naming)

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

type Invoice struct{
    Name string
    Id int
}

// Interface to implement
type IDer interface {
    ID() int
}
// Interface implementation for Invoice
func (i Invoice) ID() int { return i.Id }

type List struct {
    Items    map[int]IDer
    last IDer
}

func (i *List) Add(index int, ider IDer) {
    i.Items[index] = ider
    i.last = ider
}

func (i *List) nextID() int {
        if i.last == nil {
          return 1
        }
    return i.last.ID() + 1
}

type Repository struct {
    invoices List
}

func main() {
    r := Repository{}
    r.invoices = List{ 
        Items: make(map[int]IDer), 
    }

    i := Invoice{}
    i.Name = "Test"
    i.Id = 1
    r.invoices.Add(1, i)
    ia := r.invoices.Items[1].(Invoice) 
    fmt.Println(ia.Name)
    fmt.Printf("Next ID: %d\n", r.invoices.nextID())


    i2 := Invoice{}
    i2.Name = "Test2"
    i2.Id = r.invoices.nextID()
    r.invoices.Add(i2.Id, i2)
    ia2 := r.invoices.Items[i2.Id].(Invoice)    
    fmt.Println(ia2.Name)
    fmt.Printf("Next ID: %d\n", r.invoices.nextID())


    i3 := Invoice{}
    i3.Name = "Test3"
    i3.Id = r.invoices.nextID()
    r.invoices.Add(i3.Id, i3)
    ia3 := r.invoices.Items[i3.Id].(Invoice)    
    fmt.Println(ia3.Name)
    fmt.Printf("Next ID: %d\n", r.invoices.nextID())
}
```

```
Test
Next ID: 2
Test2
Next ID: 3
Test3
Next ID: 4

Program exited.
```

Kudos to @dm03514 for mentioning "Type assertions" https://tour.golang.org/methods/15

Comment: just so you are aware, the same with a slice https://play.golang.org/p/DPQ3cm7lSbJ I dont assume to know better your requirements, just sharing.

Comment: thanks for the additional thoughts about this. as my plan is to add invoices to the map using their Id as key, this isn't exactly the way i can easily use. `invoices[invoice.Id] = invoice`. Maybe the case, that i want to implement a restful api makes my intention clear. POST /invoices creates a new invoice GET /invoices/{invoice.Id} gets the invoice by id simply by getting the value of the map with the respecting key.